# Why am I getting this error after removing vi? “No vim found, using vi”

Tags: vim, vi, fedora-33

I'm on Fedora 33 Server. I've removed `vi` and installed `vim-enhanced`:

```
dnf remove vi
dnf install vim-enhanced
```

But I get this error on using `vim` command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# vim
No vim found, using vi, press ENTER to continue
-bash: vi: command not found
[root@localhost ~]#
```

This is how to my `$PATH` looks like:

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo $PATH
/root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Though /usr/bin path exists in `$PATH`, I've to explicitly write the path every time I need to execute `vim` command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# /usr/bin/vim
```

Please help me understand what is going on.

Comment: Somehow I missed that this question was already answered 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fedora 33 Server, `vim` command is an alias to `vi` by default, which is visible when we run `which vim` command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# which vim
alias vim='read -rep $'\''No vim found, using vi, press ENTER to continue\n'\'' -n1 -t 20 -s && vi'
        /usr/bin/read
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Or by simply executing the `alias` command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# alias
alias cp='cp -i'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias vim='read -rep $'\''No vim found, using vi, press ENTER to continue\n'\'' -n1 -t 20 -s && vi'
alias which='(alias; declare -f) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot'
alias xzegrep='xzegrep --color=auto'
alias xzfgrep='xzfgrep --color=auto'
alias xzgrep='xzgrep --color=auto'
alias zegrep='zegrep --color=auto'
alias zfgrep='zfgrep --color=auto'
alias zgrep='zgrep --color=auto'
[root@localhost ~]#
```

The solution to the problem is that we just need to unlias `vim` like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# unalias vim
[root@localhost ~]#
```

And the `vim` command will work as usual after that.